# Need fill_in_blank_1000_from_test_score.pkl file for NGNN Implementation, Can someone help me with it or its alternative?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

While we are replicating the implementation of **NGNN Dressing as a whole pape**r, I am stuck on one pickle file which is actually required to progress further i.e. **fill_in_blank_1000_from_test_score.pkl**.

Can someone help by sharing the same, else with its alternative?

*Github implementation doesn't contain the same!*
https://github.com/CRIPAC-DIG/NGNN

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use `main_score.py` (which requires the `fill_in_blank_1000_from_test_score.pkl` pickle), it's obsolete - only authors fail to mention this in the README. The problem was raised in [this issue](https://github.com/CRIPAC-DIG/NGNN/issues/6). Long story short, use another "main": `main_multi_modal.py`.

One of the comments explains in details how to proceed, I will copy it here so that it does not get lost:

> 1. Download the pre-processed dataset from the authors (the one on Google Drive, around 7 GB)
> 2. Download the "normal" dataset in order to get the text to the images (the one on Github, only a few MBs)
> 3. Change all the folder paths in the files to your corresponding ones
> 4. run "onehot_embedding.py" to create the textual features (The rest of the pre-processing was already done by the authors)
> 5. run "main_multi_modal.py" to train. In the end of the file you can adjust the config of the network (Beta, d, T etc.), so the file
>      "Config.py" is useless here.
> 6. If you want to train several instances in the for-loop, you need to reset the graph at the begining of the training. Just add
>      "tf.reset_default_graph()" at the start of the function "cm_ggnn()"
>      With this setup, I could reproduce the results fairly well with the
>      same accuracy as in the paper.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way, as it asks for the pkl still

Comment: @AnujaySaraf Which line? I don't think I have seen code that would ask for the pickle.